# How to handle multiple open windows

Tags: qtp

In Windows application if script is written for one window and if is opening for more than one time the same window  then the scripts fail and through error.

Comment: The question is not really clear. Do you want to know a) how to AVOID opening the window more than one time, or b) how to adress multiple instances of a specific window? That's quite a difference. TestGeeK's answer adresses option a) only.

Comment: I also wonder why you don't accept any of the answers given for your five other questions. Come on!

Answer (score 1):

For such Situation.. Why don't you add a Check in your script. check whether Application exist or not.

Eg:

```
   if javawindow(xxxxx).Exist(0) then
      ' some code for not opening the same window.          
   else
      'some code for opening the window.
   end if
```